# Does JS functions and lambdas saved on the code segment of the proccess?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Do the lambdas and the functions saved on the 4'th part: 'text'/code segments(it had multiple names)?

---

#### Why am I asking

I know that objects are disposable by the garbage collector and I remember that nothing on the code-segment will be deleted until the process is destroyed so **how does Javascript claims that functions are objects?**

Comment: I doubt a modern js compiler even has these traditional "data" and "text" segments, especially when it uses a jit compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the lambdas and the functions saved on the 4th part: 'text'/code segments(it had multiple names)?

Yes. But **the instances of those functions** are saved on heap segment.

JavaScript GC collects instances of the function, not the function itself which is just code.

Comment: Ho, so in a code base with multiple lambdas that get created automatically, does the process can get out of memory?

Comment: Yes. functions are just instances of `Function`.